# Simple Java MIDI player

Tags: java, object-oriented, mvc, swing, audio

I created a simple program that allows you to create and play MIDI sounds.
I've used the MVC approach and I’d like to know if there are any improvements to be made regarding the design and structure of the classes? Have I used a constants class correctly? I also feel that the `checkBoxArray`in the `Midi` class should be in a separate class. Should it be?

Please also let me know of any improvements to be made on the readability and general layout of the program.

**For those interested, I've updated my code with the advice given on this thread: [Simple Java MIDI player followup](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/simple-java-midi-player-followup)**

**BeatBox (main class)**

```
package BeatBox;


public class BeatBox {
    GUI gui;
    Midi midi;

    public BeatBox(){
        midi = new Midi();
        gui = new GUI(midi);
        midi.setUpMidi();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BeatBox();
    }
}
```

**GUI class**

```
package BeatBox;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {
    private Midi midi;

    public GUI(Midi midi){
        this.midi = midi;
        buildGUI();
    }

    // buildGUI - creates the GUI for the beat box program
    void buildGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cyber BeatBox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 350));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        // Instrument names
        Box nameBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        for(int i = 0; i < BeatBoxConstants.NUM_INSTRUMENTS; i++){
            nameBox.add(new Label(BeatBoxConstants.instrumentNames[i]));
        }

        // Check box
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(16, 16);
        grid.setVgap(0);
        grid.setHgap(2);
        JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(grid);
        for(int i = 0; i < BeatBoxConstants.NUM_INSTRUMENTS; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < BeatBoxConstants.NUM_BEATS; j++) {
                JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
                checkBoxPanel.add(checkBox);
                midi.checkBoxArray[i][j] = checkBox;
            }
        }

        // Buttons
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");

        startButton.addActionListener(new StartButtonListener());
        pauseButton.addActionListener(new GUI.PauseButtonListener());

        buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(pauseButton);

        // Add everything to the frame
        frame.add(BorderLayout.WEST, nameBox);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, checkBoxPanel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.EAST, buttonsPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // LISTENERS
    private class StartButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            midi.buildTrackAndStart();
            midi.startSequencer();
        }
    }

    private class PauseButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            midi.pauseSequencer();
        }
    }
}
```

**Midi class (used to create the sounds)**

```
package BeatBox;

import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class Midi {
    private Sequencer sequencer;
    private Sequence seq;
    private Track track;
    JCheckBox[][] checkBoxArray = new JCheckBox[BeatBoxConstants.NUM_INSTRUMENTS][BeatBoxConstants.NUM_BEATS];

    // buildTrackAndStart - used to create and begin playing the newly created track
    void buildTrackAndStart(){
        try {
            seq.deleteTrack(track);
            track = seq.createTrack();
            makeTrack();
            sequencer.setSequence(seq);
            sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }catch(InvalidMidiDataException invalidMidiDataException){
            invalidMidiDataException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // makeBeat - this creates the noteOn and noteOff beats
    private void makeBeat(int key, int tick) throws InvalidMidiDataException{
        track.add(makeEvent(144, 9, key, 100, tick));
        track.add(makeEvent(128, 9, key, 100, tick + 2));
    }

    // makeEvent - creates the notes for the track
    private MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) throws InvalidMidiDataException{
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        return new MidiEvent(a, tick);
    }

    // makeTrack - creates the sound track based on the check boxes selected by the user
    private void makeTrack() throws InvalidMidiDataException{
        for(int i = 0; i < BeatBoxConstants.NUM_INSTRUMENTS; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < BeatBoxConstants.NUM_BEATS; j++){
                if(checkBoxArray[i][j].isSelected()){
                    makeBeat(BeatBoxConstants.instruments[i], j);
                }
            }
        }
        // Added to ensure that beat box completes the whole 16 beats before it loops again
        track.add(makeEvent(192, 9, 1, 0, BeatBoxConstants.NUM_BEATS - 1));
    }

    // setUpMidi - this sets up the sound system for the user to edit
    void setUpMidi(){
        try {
            sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();
            seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            track = seq.createTrack();
        }catch(InvalidMidiDataException invalidMidiDataException){
            invalidMidiDataException.printStackTrace();
        }catch(MidiUnavailableException midiUnavailableException){
            midiUnavailableException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // startSequencer - starts playing the sequencer
    void startSequencer(){
        sequencer.start();
    }

    // pauseSequencer - pauses the sequencer. This does not stop the sound, rather it pauses it.
    void pauseSequencer(){
        sequencer.stop();
    }
}
```

**BeatBoxConstants (holds static info to be used by the other classes)**

```
package BeatBox;

public class BeatBoxConstants {
    static final String[] instrumentNames = {"Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-Hat", "Open Hi-Hat", "Acoustic Snare", "Crash Cymbal",
            "Hand Clap", "High Tom",  "Hi Bongo", "Maracas", "Whistle", "Low Conga", "Cowbell", "Vibraslap", "Low-mid Tom",
            "High Agogo", "Open Hi Conga"};
    static final int[] instruments = {35, 42, 46, 38, 49, 39, 50, 60, 70, 72, 64, 56, 58, 47, 67, 63};

    static final int NUM_BEATS = 16;
    static final int NUM_INSTRUMENTS = instrumentNames.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't really know that much about music, so some of my assumptions might be wrong.

> Have I used a constants class correctly?

I wouldn't say so. I would only use a constants class for things which are not part of the state of any objects, and which do not expose the inner workings of objects (eg a debug field, database credentials, fixed strings for user output, etc).

The numbers in `instruments` (which should be all upper case) seem to be random numbers (as in, they are not numbers a musician would recognize, but numbers that are specific to your program). They also seem to interact with `instrumentNames`, which is not good (see below).

`NUM_INSTRUMENTS` isn't really needed at all. `NUM_BEATS` is the only value that I might leave in a constants class.

> I’d like to know if there are any improvements to be made regarding the design and structure of the classes?

One thing that directly jumped out at me is that it's really hard to see how you make the sounds of different instruments. It seems to depend on the passed `key` in `makeBeat(int key, int tick)`. The call of that depends on the order of instruments in the `instruments` constant, and that it is in the correct order regarding `instrumentNames`, and displayed in the same order inside the GUI.

It's never a good idea to put that much weight on the order of different lists being correct (because those lists work independently of each other).

I would introduce an explicit `Instrument` class, which has a `name` and a `key` (if key is the technical term).

I would then pack the whole `tick` thing into a class as well (because of my lack of music knowledge it's hard to say how. Some ideas: Could a list of `tick`s be part of an instrument? Or could there be `TickList`s which each own one instrument?).

> I also feel that the `checkBoxArray` in the `Midi` class should be in a separate class. Should it be?

Yes. Your `Midi` class is basically your model and controller, but it definitely isn't your GUI, so it shouldn't have `JCheckBox`s. Instead, it should have the `Instrument`/`TickList` structure described above, which it can then expose to the GUI.

**Misc**

- a reset button would be great for usability, and should be easy to add.
- don't import `*`, instead make all your imports explicit, so readers know what classes you use.
- use JavaDoc style method comments (they are easier to read as they make input parameters and output explicit, and they can be displayed in IDE tooltips, published on the web, etc).
- Naming: `seq` can be a bit confusing, as it's unclear if it is sequencer or sequence; I would just write it out. At first, I thought `comd` is some music term, but as it stands for `command`, just write it out as well. Same for `chan` (`channel`).

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I’m a bit unsure what’s meant about the correct use of a constants class. Isn’t `NUM_BEATS` also part of the object (e.g. `checkBoxArray` in the `Midi` class)?

Also, should `instruments` and `instrumentNames` be replaced by `INSTRUMENTS` and `INSTRUMENT_NAMES`? If so, then what’s the definition of a constant in Java, because I thought that constants are immutable but with final arrays you can still change the elements? Or is the definition of a constant a static final variable?

Comment: @Calculus5000 I assumed `NUM_BEATS` is something like a configuration? Eg, it could also be 20 and it wouldn't really matter for the rest of the code (only the sound produced)? And yes, static final variables are conventionally written all upper case. And in Java, there isn't really a thing as a constant object (well, a final instance of an immutable object could be seen as one, I guess). But by convention, static final + all upper case signals that something should be considered a constant.

Comment: Also, should I break up the code in `buildGUI()` in the `GUI` class?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `NUM_BEATS` can be any number (16 was arbitrarily chosen). I'm just a bit confused as to why that can be a constant and `instrumentNames` shouldn't?

Comment: @Calculus5000 I would probably do so, yes. Maybe create functions for the creation of the main frame, creation of checkboxes, and creation of buttons (basically anything you signal via comments right now). And `NUM_BEATS` doesn't seem to have any meaning inside the program. But `instrumentNames` does. If I change one of the strings, your whole program would behave rather oddly (because my changed string doesn't fit in with the number stored in `instruments`). Additionally, creating a class/enum for instruments will probably lead to cleaner code in general.